# Я понаставила и поубирала запятых и тире, - права ли я?

Tags: пунктуация

> Оттого погода может меняться и по пять раз на дню: разбудить
>   ослепительным солнцем, к полудню опустить туман, после обеда зарядить
>   дождём – лишь для того, чтобы сильным ветром разбросать облака к
>   закату, и, наконец, поздним вечером отпустить с гор пронизывающий
>   холод, который подгоняет запоздалого путника, дабы погрузить тёмные
>   улицы в истинный сон.

Все знаки даны мне (нам) на откуп.

Двоеточие сама нарисовала... Что ещё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

Оттого погода может меняться и по пять раз на дню: разбудить ослепительным солнцем, к полудню опустить туман, после обеда зарядить дождём  **лишь для того, чтобы сильным ветром разбросать облака к закату, — и наконец поздним вечером отпустить с гор пронизывающий холод,** который подгоняет запоздалого путника, дабы погрузить тёмные улицы в истинный сон.

**Пояснение**

1) У меня  **присоединительное тире** перед последней распространенной инфинитивной конструкцией.

2) ***Наконец*** — наречие. Оно может быть вводным словом при перечислении, но это, как я думаю, обычно касается доводов при рассуждении.

3) Постановка тире не перед "лишь для того" **не кажется обоснованной.** Если выделять придаточное, то как вводную конструкцию, а тогда нужно два тире. Лучше разделить текст после двоеточия на две части.

Примечание: **повтора слова** опустить, хорошо бы его заменить.

Например: покрыть город (окрестности) туманом, расстелить туман.